# Choosing component based on string only without switch in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is basically what I'm trying to do:

```
import image_a from './a.jpg';
import image_b from './b.jpg';
import image_c from './c.jpg';

class Title extends Component {
  render() {
    // other code here, this.props.param = some string

    var letters = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < this.props.param.length; i++) {
      var componentName = "image_" + this.props.param[i];
      letters.push(<img src={componentName}></img>); // DOESNT WORK
    }

    // other code here
  }
}
```

I have a bunch of images, and I want to dynamically render them from a string parameter. I could do a series of

```
if (this.props.text[i] === 'a') {
    letters.push(<img src={image_a}></img>);
}
if (this.props.text[i] === 'b') {
....
```

**Is my approach possible with some tweaking? Or am I going to have to resort to basically a series of conditional statements?**

Comment: Use a `Map` or the keys of an object to lookup the image.

Comment: Would that involve having to add all the key-value pairs in the constructor between letters and objects? Not sure what you mean

Comment: Right, `var images = { a: image_a, b: image_b, c: image_c };`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a file with an object with all the images:

```
export const images = {img1: require('./img1.jpg')}
```

Then you could do

```
import images from './images';

class Title extends Component {

render () {

  this.props.params.map((value,index)=> !images[value]
    ? null
    : <img src={images[value]} key={index} />
  ));
  }
}
```

Note that I assume `value` is a string, and you should return null when conditionally rendering (using `if`)
You could also use a `for loop` and an `if statement` But I like it better this way

Answer (score 0):

From what I am understanding, you want to render a bunch of images from `this.props.param` which can be a multi-character string?

If that is the case, you can make your life much simpler if you replaced the `import` statements with `require` so you can format and make your life much easier.

```
const characterImages = {
  a: require('./a.jpg'),
  b: require('./b.jpg'),
  c: require('./c.jpg')
}
```

From there...you can just `split('')` `this.props.param` and map it in `render`:

```
class Title extends Component {
  render() {
    // other code here, this.props.param = some string

    // (this.props.param || '') resolves error if param not set
    // .toString() resolves error and converts to string if param is just a number

    { (this.props.param || '').toString().split('').map((letter, i) => 
      <img key={i} src={characterImages[letter]}></img>
    )}

    // other code here
  }
}
```